# Error:(20,63)Expected ')' (to close '(' at coulmn 55), got =

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local camera = game.Workspace.Camera

local cutsceneTime = 12

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    cutsceneTime,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
    Enum.EasingDirection.out,
    0,
    false,
    0
)

function tween(Test1,Test2)
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    camera.CFrame = Test1.CFrame

    local tween = TweenService:Create{camera, tweenInfo, (CFrame = Test2.CFrame)} 
    tween:play()

    wait(cutsceneTime)

    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
end

wait(1)

tween(game.Workspace.Test1,game.Workspace.Test2)
local camera = game.Workspace.Camera
```

Comment: I swear these are the exact words. the error is CFrame = Test2.CFrame

Comment: Hi! You should edit your question to correctly format the code as Lua code so that would-be-answerers can spend less time deciphering it. (Press the Edit button, then select all 
of the code and press the `{}` button).

Comment: Looks like you have parentheses around the key/value pair.

Comment: Third argument is a table.  Replace `(CFrame = Test2.CFrame)` with `{CFrame = Test2.CFrame}`

Answer (score 0):

Like [@Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847592/egor-skriptunoff) said, you should replace `(CFrame = Test2.CFrame)` with `{CFrame = Test2.CFrame}`, because the third argument of `TweenService:Create` should be a [Dictionary](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Table). You should also replace `{camera, tweenInfo, {CFrame = Test2.CFrame}}` with `(camera, tweenInfo, {CFrame = Test2.CFrame})` because function arguments should be entered inside a tuple.

Final code:

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local camera = game.Workspace.Camera

local cutsceneTime = 12

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    cutsceneTime,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Sine,
    Enum.EasingDirection.out,
    0,
    false,
    0
)

function tween(Test1,Test2)
    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    camera.CFrame = Test1.CFrame

    local tween = TweenService:Create(camera, tweenInfo, {CFrame = Test2.CFrame}) 
    tween:play()

    wait(cutsceneTime)

    camera.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Custom
end

wait(1)

tween(game.Workspace.Test1,game.Workspace.Test2)
local camera = game.Workspace.Camera
```